# How can I get the value returned by a function triggered by a mouse event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the html code below:

```
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("div").on("mouseenter", function (){
          myidx = $(this).index();
          return myidx;
});

var x = y // The value myidx;
```

I want to assign the output of the function executed on `mouseenter` which is the value of `myidx` to var `x`. So that: var `x` = the value of `myidx`.

I have tried my experiments and have done a lot of research but I've not found a way of accessing the results returned by a function inside the jquery method "mouseenter". Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define variable `x`, which will be standby in-case the `mouseenter` event is triggered so that the value of `$(this).index();` will be assigned to it.

Second, setting the `var x` to global by removing the `var` before `x` will make it accessible outside the function that generated that value.

```
var x;

$("div").on("mouseenter", function (){
   x = $(this).index();
});
```

Now `var x` will output `6` in your case incase you `alert x` anywhere in your js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the *return* value since you didn't call the event handler function.

You could assign the value to a global (which you are doing with `myidx`), but then you would have to wait until the event had happened before using it.

You couldn't use the value from the event between assigning the event handler and the event happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below to update `x`;

```
var x;

$("div").on("mouseenter", function (){
    x = $(this).index();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var x;
$("div").on("mouseenter", function (){
      myidx = $(this).index();
      x = myidx;
});
```

Comment: `myidx` variable looks like useless one in this example.